# sealing violation: package oracle.jdbc.pool is sealed oracle UCP connection pooling

Tags: java, ojdbc, ucp

My project was using `ojdbc6` with `c3p0` connection pooling . This i moved to `ojdbc8` and `UCP(Oracle's universal connection pooling)`. But i am getting below error:

`UCP Config` used:

```
try
                {
                    //Creating a pool-enabled data source
                    pds= PoolDataSourceFactory.getPoolDataSource();

                    String dbURL="jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION = (CONNECT_TIMEOUT= 15)(RETRY_COUNT=20)(RETRY_DELAY=3) (ADDRESS_LIST =(LOAD_BALANCE=on)(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP) (HOST = vm-host-101) (PORT = 1521))) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = S1NAME)))";

          //this is where am using that package 
                    pds.setConnectionFactoryClassName("oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource");
                    pds.setURL(dbURL);
                    pds.setUser("username");
                    pds.setPassword("password");
                    pds.setInitialPoolSize(5);
                    pds.setMinPoolSize(5);
                    pds.setMaxPoolSize(10);
                    pds.setFastConnectionFailoverEnabled(false);
                    return pds;
                }
                catch(SQLException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return pds;

            }
```

Error:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Unable to create factory class instance with provided factory class name: java.lang.SecurityException: sealing violation: package oracle.jdbc.pool is sealed
    at oracle.ucp.util.UCPErrorHandler.newSQLException(UCPErrorHandler.java:456) ~[ucp-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.ucp.util.UCPErrorHandler.throwSQLException(UCPErrorHandler.java:133) ~[ucp-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl.initConnectionFactory(PoolDataSourceImpl.java:3243) ~[ucp-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    at oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceImpl.createUniversalConnectionPool(PoolDataSourceImpl.java:1105) ~[ucp-12.2.0.1.jar:12.2.0.1.0]
    ... 61 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: sealing violation: package oracle.jdbc.pool is sealed
```

I understand the error will come when we have 2 `class` loaded from same `package`. But i checked in external dependencies in `intellij` and also tried `mvn dependency:tree` command of `maven`. I couldn't find duplicate `OJDBC jars` in `classpath`.

Is there any other reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This typically happens when you have **more than one** `ojdbc*.jar` in your `classpath`.

In your question you clearly state you have verified that there was no **duplicate** but there must be one. If you load `ojdbc8` from `Maven` then you need to make sure that it's not manually added from the local `filesystem`.

Same thing for `ucp.jar`. You may want to scan your `filesystem` for `ojdbc6.jar or ojdbc6dms.jar (or ojdbc8.jar and ojdbc8dms.jar or ojdbc10 - just scan for  ojdbc*)` and rename the jars to something else (or remove them).

It's sometimes cryptic - depending on your framework - to see your full classpath. On `linux a "ps -af" command` will display the full command line that was used to launch java and these sometimes provides useful information about the `classpath`.

Comment: yeah this is the reason. generally its hard to find out the duplicate `JAR` when we check in IDE. The trick is, take the out put `JAR` from target folder. unzip it. you can use this command  `jar -xvf project.jar` . The same way unzip all the internal jars as well. We can find out the duplicate one. :)